# Cropping Video from scrollview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, video-editing, avmutablecomposition

I  would like to implement functionality like below. i have used scrollView and based on zoom scale I tried  to crop video but didn’t able to get same result. Can any one help me with this?

Link for the functioanlity which I want : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dqGPTS494JwMktjGyPbzbIz5TG8RdyV1/view?usp=share_link

Reference url from where I tried to implement such functionality : https://www.kodeco.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Result which I am getting :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14D82rGPOiJBStNipXu7r-gaeosIYJz0U/view?usp=share_link

Video which I used for sample:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14D82rGPOiJBStNipXu7r-gaeosIYJz0U/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. We need to see the code you've written in order to offer any kind of suggestions on what to change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.